# How can you use yield return with microsoft graph api v5 PageIterator

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Currently I'm using AsyncEnumerable to get group members from Graph API

```cs
public async IAsyncEnumerable<Microsoft.Graph.User> LoadGroupMembers(string GroupId)
{
    if (graphClient == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(graphClient));

    var users = await graphClient.Groups[GroupId].Members
        .Request()
        .GetAsync();

    var count = 0;    
    do
    {
        foreach (var member in users)
        {
            if (member is Microsoft.Graph.User user)
            {
                yield return user;
            }
        }
    }
    while (users.NextPageRequest != null && (users = await users.NextPageRequest.GetAsync()).Count > 0);
}
```

The new v5 API gets rid of NextPageRequest and replaces it with PageIterator.

```cs
var users = await graphClient.Groups[GroupId].Members
        .GetAsync();

var pageIterator = PageIterator<User,UserCollectionResponse>
    .CreatePageIterator(
        graphClient,
        users,
        // Callback executed for each item in the collection
        (u) =>
        {
            //Don't think I can yield return from here
            Console.WriteLine(u.UserName);
            return true;
        }
    );

await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
```

Is there another way to yield return the records?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: @Boomerang No, I stayed of v4 for that project

Answer (score 1):

I use the following for IAsyncEnumerable support with SDK version 5, which borrows from other peoples answers and the internal concepts used within the out of the box PageIterator type (which also uses some reflection internally).

```
public static class CollectionPageExtensions
{
    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<TEntity> AsAsyncEnumerable<TEntity, TCollectionPage>(this TCollectionPage collectionPage, IBaseClient graphClient, [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        where TCollectionPage : IBackedModel, IParsable, IAdditionalDataHolder, new()
    {
        TCollectionPage? currentPage = collectionPage;
        do
        {
            var items = currentPage.BackingStore?.Get<List<TEntity>?>("value");

            foreach (TEntity? item in items)
            {
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                yield return item;
            }

            var nextPage = await currentPage.GetNextPageAsync<TEntity, TCollectionPage>(graphClient, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (nextPage == null)
            {
                yield break;
            }

            currentPage = nextPage;
        }
        while (currentPage is not null);
    }

    private static async Task<TCollectionPage?> GetNextPageAsync<TEntity, TCollectionPage>(this TCollectionPage collectionPage, IBaseClient graphClient, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        where TCollectionPage : IBackedModel, IParsable, IAdditionalDataHolder, new()
    {
        var nextPageLink = ExtractNextLinkFromParsable(collectionPage);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextPageLink))
        {
            return default;
        }

        // Call the MSGraph API to get the next page of results and set that page as the currentPage.
        var nextPageRequestInformation = new RequestInformation
        {
            HttpMethod = Method.GET,
            UrlTemplate = nextPageLink
        };
        // if we have a request configurator, modify the request as desired then execute it to get the next page
        return await graphClient.RequestAdapter.SendAsync(nextPageRequestInformation, (parseNode) => new TCollectionPage()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private static string ExtractNextLinkFromParsable<TCollectionPage>(TCollectionPage parsableCollection, string nextLinkPropertyName = "OdataNextLink")
        where TCollectionPage : IBackedModel, IParsable, IAdditionalDataHolder, new()
    {
        var nextLinkProperty = parsableCollection.GetType().GetProperty(nextLinkPropertyName);
        if (nextLinkProperty != null &&
            nextLinkProperty.GetValue(parsableCollection, null) is string nextLinkString
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextLinkString))
        {
            return nextLinkString;
        }

        if (parsableCollection.AdditionalData == null)
            return string.Empty;

        // the next link property may not be defined in the response schema so we also check its presence in the additional data bag
        if (parsableCollection.AdditionalData.TryGetValue(CoreConstants.OdataInstanceAnnotations.NextLink, out var nextLink))
        {
            if (nextLink != null)
                return nextLink.ToString();
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

I have also included this info on this ticket: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/733#issuecomment-1884611064